# can I ask couchdb `_change` API to return all document change history?

Tags: json, rest, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-futon

for all the documents that have been updated multiple times (not deleted, just updated), the records returned by `_change` only contains the latest revision.

if I query `db/doc?revs_info=true`, I can see all the revisions are available, but I don't want to query individual documents to get this list.

is there an option to let `_change` to return all revision history?